# Why are there gaps in a PortfolioAnalytics mean-std efficent frontier?

Tags: r, portfolio, r-portfolioanalytics

I’m experiencing unexpected results from the create.EfficientFrontier function in the PortfolioAnalytics package (v1.0.3636).  I’m trying to create an efficient frontier using mean-variance optimization.  All my constraints are linear.  I set the n.portfolios = 100 in the call.  It returns only the 32 portfolios shown in both a table and chart below.  The unexpected behavior is that there are gaps in the frontier.  While there are quite a few gaps, one of the larger ones is between result.62 and result.94.  There’s a large jump in returns and risk between the two points.  This is what I mean by gap. I do not understand for example why there are no points with a mean near 0.04.  I can use the optimize.portfolio function with a target of 0.04 and find a solution.  The cov vector is 54x54 so I did not include the data. If someone would like it, I will post it and the ret vector.
`R<-xts(mvrnorm(n=120,cmf.tax.adjusted$ret,cmf.tax.adjusted$cov,
   empirical=TRUE),order.by=seq(as.Date("2000/12/31"),by="month",length.out=120))
eff<-create.EfficientFrontier(R=R,portfolio=pspec,
   type="mean-sd",match.col="StdDev",n.portfolios=100)`

And here is the code to produce a return = 0.04

```
pspec1<-pspec
pspec1<- add.objective(portfolio=pspec1, type="return", name="mean",target=.04,indexnum=1)
opt1<-optimize.portfolio(R,pspec1,optimize_method="ROI")
```

The pspec is shown after the efficient frontier

[image]
32 points produced by create.EfficientFrontier

```
                mean     StdDev
result.1  0.004818413 0.03159756
result.2  0.005285545 0.03159756
result.3  0.005752677 0.03159757
result.9  0.008555470 0.03229847
result.10 0.009022602 0.03257118
result.11 0.009489734 0.03287380
result.12 0.009956866 0.03319658
result.13 0.010423998 0.03356550
result.23 0.015095319 0.04085273
result.25 0.016029583 0.04269109
result.26 0.016496715 0.04363220
result.27 0.016963847 0.04458671
result.29 0.017898112 0.04653263
result.31 0.018832376 0.04855024
result.32 0.019299508 0.04958316
result.33 0.019766640 0.05063005
result.52 0.028642150 0.07234101
result.53 0.029109282 0.07355126
result.54 0.029576414 0.07476445
result.55 0.030043546 0.07598045
result.56 0.030510678 0.07719941
result.57 0.030977810 0.07842371
result.59 0.031912074 0.08090880
result.60 0.032379206 0.08217014
result.61 0.032846338 0.08344324
result.62 0.033313470 0.08472759
result.94 0.048261697 0.13508563
result.95 0.048728829 0.13692166
result.96 0.049195961 0.13901611
result.97 0.049663094 0.14122860
result.98 0.050130226 0.14345820
result.99 0.050597358 0.14571323
```

pspec:

```
$assets
       USCash-taxed       STUSTsy-taxed       LTUSTsy-taxed        USTIPs-taxed        USCore-taxed 
         0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784 
   GlobalCore-taxed         HiYld-taxed     BankLoans-taxed  EMNonLclDebt-taxed   EMLocalDebt-taxed 
         0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784 
   EMCurrency-taxed   Commodities-taxed          REIT-taxed       USLarge-taxed       USSmall-taxed 
         0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784 
   EAFEEquity-taxed      EMEquity-taxed        USCash-defer       STUSTsy-defer       LTUSTsy-defer 
         0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784 
       USTIPs-defer        USCore-defer    GlobalCore-defer         HiYld-defer     BankLoans-defer 
         0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784 
 EMNonLclDebt-defer   EMLocalDebt-defer    EMCurrency-defer   Commodities-defer          REIT-defer 
         0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784 
      USLarge-defer       USSmall-defer    EAFEEquity-defer      EMEquity-defer       USCash-exempt 
         0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784 
     STUSTsy-exempt      LTUSTsy-exempt       USTIPs-exempt       USCore-exempt   GlobalCore-exempt 
         0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784 
       HiYld-exempt    BankLoans-exempt EMNonLclDebt-exempt  EMLocalDebt-exempt   EMCurrency-exempt 
         0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784 
 Commodities-exempt         REIT-exempt      USLarge-exempt      USSmall-exempt   EAFEEquity-exempt 
         0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784          0.01960784 
    EMEquity-exempt 
         0.01960784 

$enabled_constraints
$enabled_constraints[[1]]
An object containing 6 constraints.
Some constraints are of type nonlinear.

$enabled_constraints[[2]]
An object containing 5 constraints.
Some constraints are of type nonlinear.

$enabled_constraints[[3]]
An object containing 6 constraints.
Some constraints are of type nonlinear.


$disabled_constraints
list()

$enabled_objectives
$enabled_objectives[[1]]
$name
[1] "mean"

$target
NULL

$arguments
list()

$enabled
[1] TRUE

$multiplier
[1] -1

$call
add.objective(portfolio = pspec, type = "return", name = "mean")

attr(,"class")
[1] "return_objective" "objective"       

$enabled_objectives[[2]]
$name
[1] "StdDev"

$target
NULL

$arguments
$arguments$portfolio_method
[1] "single"


$enabled
[1] TRUE

$multiplier
[1] 1

$call
add.objective(portfolio = pspec, type = "risk", name = "StdDev")

attr(,"class")
[1] "portfolio_risk_objective" "objective"               


$disabled_objectives
list()

attr(,"class")
[1] "summary.portfolio"
```

Comment: Sometimes the desired return is just not achievable. Can you add the stocks in your universe to the plot?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it this way?

```
# Economist at Large
# Modern Portfolio Theory
# Use solve.QP to solve for efficient frontier
# Last Edited 5/3/13

# This file uses the solve.QP function in the quadprog package to solve for the
# efficient frontier.
# Since the efficient frontier is a parabolic function, we can find the solution
# that minimizes portfolio variance and then vary the risk premium to find
# points along the efficient frontier. Then simply find the portfolio with the
# largest Sharpe ratio (expected return / sd) to identify the most
# efficient portfolio

library(stockPortfolio) # Base package for retrieving returns
library(ggplot2) # Used to graph efficient frontier
library(reshape2) # Used to melt the data
library(quadprog) #Needed for solve.QP

# Create the portfolio using ETFs, incl. hypothetical non-efficient allocation
stocks <- c(
 "VTSMX" = .0,
 "SPY" = .20,
 "EFA" = .10,
 "IWM" = .10,
 "VWO" = .30,
 "LQD" = .20,
 "HYG" = .10)

# Retrieve returns, from earliest start date possible (where all stocks have
# data) through most recent date
returns <- getReturns(names(stocks[-1]), freq="week") #Currently, drop index

#### Efficient Frontier function ####
eff.frontier <- function (returns, short="no", max.allocation=NULL,
 risk.premium.up=.5, risk.increment=.005){
 # return argument should be a m x n matrix with one column per security
 # short argument is whether short-selling is allowed; default is no (short
 # selling prohibited)max.allocation is the maximum % allowed for any one
 # security (reduces concentration) risk.premium.up is the upper limit of the
 # risk premium modeled (see for loop below) and risk.increment is the
 # increment (by) value used in the for loop

 covariance <- cov(returns)
 print(covariance)
 n <- ncol(covariance)

 # Create initial Amat and bvec assuming only equality constraint
 # (short-selling is allowed, no allocation constraints)
 Amat <- matrix (1, nrow=n)
 bvec <- 1
 meq <- 1

 # Then modify the Amat and bvec if short-selling is prohibited
 if(short=="no"){
 Amat <- cbind(1, diag(n))
 bvec <- c(bvec, rep(0, n))
 }

 # And modify Amat and bvec if a max allocation (concentration) is specified
 if(!is.null(max.allocation)){
 if(max.allocation > 1 | max.allocation <0){
 stop("max.allocation must be greater than 0 and less than 1")
 }
 if(max.allocation * n < 1){
 stop("Need to set max.allocation higher; not enough assets to add to 1")
 }
 Amat <- cbind(Amat, -diag(n))
 bvec <- c(bvec, rep(-max.allocation, n))
 }

 # Calculate the number of loops
 loops <- risk.premium.up / risk.increment + 1
 loop <- 1

 # Initialize a matrix to contain allocation and statistics
 # This is not necessary, but speeds up processing and uses less memory
 eff <- matrix(nrow=loops, ncol=n+3)
 # Now I need to give the matrix column names
 colnames(eff) <- c(colnames(returns), "Std.Dev", "Exp.Return", "sharpe")

 # Loop through the quadratic program solver
 for (i in seq(from=0, to=risk.premium.up, by=risk.increment)){
 dvec <- colMeans(returns) * i # This moves the solution along the EF
 sol <- solve.QP(covariance, dvec=dvec, Amat=Amat, bvec=bvec, meq=meq)
 eff[loop,"Std.Dev"] <- sqrt(sum(sol$solution*colSums((covariance*sol$solution))))
 eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] <- as.numeric(sol$solution %*% colMeans(returns))
 eff[loop,"sharpe"] <- eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] / eff[loop,"Std.Dev"]
 eff[loop,1:n] <- sol$solution
 loop <- loop+1
 }

 return(as.data.frame(eff))
}

# Run the eff.frontier function based on no short and 50% alloc. restrictions
eff <- eff.frontier(returns=returns$R, short="no", max.allocation=.50,
 risk.premium.up=1, risk.increment=.001)

# Find the optimal portfolio
eff.optimal.point <- eff[eff$sharpe==max(eff$sharpe),]

# graph efficient frontier
# Start with color scheme
ealred <- "#7D110C"
ealtan <- "#CDC4B6"
eallighttan <- "#F7F6F0"
ealdark <- "#423C30"

ggplot(eff, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return)) + geom_point(alpha=.1, color=ealdark) +
 geom_point(data=eff.optimal.point, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return, label=sharpe),
 color=ealred, size=5) +
 annotate(geom="text", x=eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev,
 y=eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return,
 label=paste("Risk: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev*100, digits=3),"\nReturn: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return*100, digits=4),"%\nSharpe: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$sharpe*100, digits=2), "%", sep=""),
 hjust=0, vjust=1.2) +
 ggtitle("Efficient Frontier\nand Optimal Portfolio") +
 labs(x="Risk (standard deviation of portfolio)", y="Return") +
 theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill=eallighttan),
 text=element_text(color=ealdark),
 plot.title=element_text(size=24, color=ealred))
ggsave("Efficient Frontier.png")
```

Below is a link where you can learn more about what the code is doing.

http://economistatlarge.com/portfolio-theory/r-optimized-portfolio

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I can use quadprog etc to build an efficient frontier with my inputs.  I was hoping to use a package.  Also, my problem is that I prefer to use forecast values (at least for return) rather than historical data.  But your approach does work.  I would like to understand PortfolioAnalytics a bit better.